# Was there a Security Council meeting that continued through the night until a resolution was agreed?

Tags: united-nations, unsc

Some time ago I attended a Model United Nations conference and participated in the Security Council. One of the members tried several times to extend the time of the meeting but not for a specific time. He wanted us to continue work on the resolution until it was finished.

As motivation, he said:

> "Let's us do it like in **{this UN meeting}**. They worked until midnight."

**Which specific real UN meeting does he mean?**

Has there been a Security Council meeting which worked on a resolution for such a long time that they worked until midnight?

Comment: Its only the fate of the world we are talking about here.  Why would you want to put yourself out?  Just defer to Libya or Iran

Comment: I'm very confused by your question and have helped run HMUN. I don't know what you're getting at?

Comment: @kcchristianson - Mock UN its a HS/Univ level exercise where students role play  a UN meeting to try to solve a mock problem diplomatically.

Comment: @kcchristianson - The jist of the question SEEMS to be that someone in MUN referenced a **specific real UN meeting** that had participants stay until midnight so they could arrive at a resolution. OP is trying to find out if such a meeting really happened in real UN.

Comment: I flagged for re-opening. The question is pretty clear.

Comment: I am pretty sure the SC meeting that resulted in a resolution that condemned Iraq in 2002 went late into the night.  Mostly because the US vetoed votes to adjourn until the situation was resolved...

Answer (score 5):

The longest UNSC meeting that I'm aware of is the [6411th](https://undocs.org/en/S/PV.6411) meeting which took place in October 2010 on the topic of *'Women and peace and security'*. It lasted from 10:10 a.m. to 10:20 p.m., a duration of just over 12 hours. This is followed by the [6917th meeting](https://undocs.org/en/S/PV.6917), on the topic of *'Protection of civilians in armed conflict'*, which lasted from 11.05 a.m. until 10:20 p.m., a duration of around 11 hours.

Many UNSC meetings have taken place through the night, the most recent that I'm aware of being the [7225th meeting](https://undocs.org/en/S/PV.7225), which lasted just 10 minutes, but started at midnight. There were also a fair number in 1990, on the topic of Iraq & Kuwait, which took place during the night, in particular, the 2932nd, 2937th, 2938th, 2939th, and 2940th sessions, but none lasted longer than three hours.

A good example of a marathon session taking place through the night came in 2002; the [4503rd meeting](https://undocs.org/en/S/PV.4503), on the topic of *'The situation in the Middle East, including the Palestinian question'* lasted from 6 p.m. on Friday March 29th through the night until it rose at 4.40 a.m., a duration of 10 hours 40 minutes.